# How to print pdf file using windows service

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, printing, windows-services, processstartinfo

I tried to print a pdf file from my windows service.It didnt work.Later i wrote a console app to print a pdf file.Console app did work!.Afterwords i i called that console app from service to print pdf file it didn'work. Why is that "print" doesnt work with windows service?      following are the code snippets i tried

```
1.Used adobe reader:
                PdfReportGeneration.Log logs = new PdfReportGeneration.Log();
                logs.writeLog("PrintDocument filepath:-" + filepath);

                Process process = new Process();
                process.StartInfo.FileName = filepath;
                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                process.StartInfo.Verb = "printTo";
                process.StartInfo.Arguments = "HP LaserJet P1005";
                process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                process.Start();
                process.WaitForInputIdle();
                process.Kill();

2. Used foxit reader/adobe reader both didnt work
    string sArgs = " /t \"" + filepath + "\" \"" + "HP LaserJet P1005" + "\"";
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\Foxit Reader.exe";
    startInfo.Verb = "printTo";
    startInfo.Arguments = sArgs;
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    System.Diagnostics.Process proc = Process.Start(startInfo);
    proc.WaitForExit(100000); // Wait a maximum of 10 sec for the process to finish
    if (!proc.HasExited)
    {
        proc.Kill();
        proc.Dispose();
       // return false;
    }*/
```

Done a lots of google bing yahoo.. no use!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service is usually run by different account. I would try to run service as user. Could be a problem that system user doesn't have mapped that printer. Service install class would look like this:

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public class ServiceInstall : Installer
{
    public ServiceInstall()
    {
        ServiceInstaller serviceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();
        ServiceProcessInstaller serviceProcessInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller();

        serviceProcessInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.User;
        serviceProcessInstaller.Username = "User";
        serviceProcessInstaller.Password = "Password";

        serviceInstaller.DisplayName = "Some Service";
        serviceInstaller.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
        serviceInstaller.ServiceName = "Some Service";

        this.Installers.Add(serviceProcessInstaller);
        this.Installers.Add(serviceInstaller);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is serviceProcessInstaller here?

Comment: As next step i would try to allow that process to have own window. Maybe you can found there what is happening in this process.

Comment: You tried admin, but are Adobe Reader and Foxit installed in that account? Please be sure to use the account where those tools are installed and run normally.

Comment: i was missing permission for this in my server serviceProcessInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.User;